Rails low level caching with Solid Cache: getting `warning: already initialized constant`
I'm trying to cache some query data using Rails "low level caching" and Solid Cache - pretty simple stuff.
Here is my caching method:
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  def self.location_name_cache
    Rails.cache.fetch(:location_names, expires_in: 15.minutes) do
      (Location.pluck(:name) + Observation.pluck(:where)).uniq
    end
  end

  # Check if a given place name already exists, defined as a Location name string.
  def self.location_name_exists(name)
    location_name_cache.member?(name)
  end

But when I unit-test my class method (using Minitest), although the tests pass, i'm getting these warnings:
warning: already initialized constant SolidCache::Record::NULL_INSTRUMENTER
warning: previous definition of NULL_INSTRUMENTER was here

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried bundle clean --force and bundle install in case it was a stale gem thing, but that's the only issue search turned up that seemed to match my case.
Here's my caching configs:
# config/application.rb
  config.cache_store = :solid_cache_store
  config.solid_cache.connects_to = { database: { writing: :cache } }

# config/environments/test.rb - idk if these are relevant
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true

# config/environments/development.rb - probably not relevant
  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join("tmp/caching-dev.txt").exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    # debugging: log fragment reads/writes
    # (it will show [cache hit] even if set to false)
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store # :mem_cache_store via application.rb
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  end

Or is this a case where the db will cache the results anyway, and a cache is inadvisable?

thanks @dbugger, i added the cache config

As it looks like you've discovered, this is a warning from the solid_cache gem code.

@dbugger ok... but what does that really tell me, though? It doesn't seem like my simple caching method should be triggering any warnings from the gem. I'm not trying to re-initialize a constant. Are you saying I may've encountered a bug in the gem?

The warning is coming from the gem - nothing you are doing

This has been debugged by the authors. Turns out the gem's error handling was swallowing cache db configuration errors. Fix is on the way.
